# ICommunicationObject.State do not work?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, faulted

**Hi,**

I create my WCF client with DuplexChannelFactory, the problem is that when I do this :

```
((ICommunicationObject)this.GetMyServiceInterfaceChannel).State
```

I get the followin exception :

**Cannot obtain fields or call methods on the instance of type 'System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject' because it is a proxy to a remote object.**

Why?

I need to check if the channel is faulted.

Edit1:

```
ClientService clientService = new ClientService();
                InstanceContext context = new InstanceContext(clientService);

                DuplexChannelFactory<My.ServiceContracts.IMyClientService> factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<My.ServiceContracts.IMyClientService>(context, connectionName);

                factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = anvandarNamn;
                factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;


                return factory.CreateChannel();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast as IClientChannel, then check the State

But be carefull that the State is only updated when you make a call. If you want to test that the channel doesn't timeout, it's not possible untill you make a call that throw the exception.

Comment: I get the exact same exception when using the IClentChannel?

Comment: Could you add the code for 'GetMyServiceInterfaceChannel' creation ?

Comment: It's because you create the DuplexChannelFactory using an InstanceContext. You have to use the State property on the InstanceContext itself